# Is it fabric of space or fabric of space-time?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime

Very quick question, in the [general relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity) is it fabric of space, fabric of space-time or both mentioned?

Answer (score 4):

General relativity does not mention any sort of fabric at all. The whole fabric idea is only an analogy used to explain *some* aspects of spacetime curvature to laypeople, but the analogy breaks down very quickly if you try to take it beyond the one concept it is intended to explain (and for that reason one could argue it's not a very good analogy).